# How to display all images into light box in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I want to display images in WordPress site in light box.If a user click a image in any post or page then that image should appear in the light box with next and prev option. If the user hit a esc key then it should disappear.Don't know where to start and how to start can anybody help?

Comment: `Wordpress plugins directory`

Comment: Either you need a plugin (there are tons of those around), or you need to include lightbox (or fancybox) jquery, make changes in the files to use it and configure it in jquery. Plugins are an easy option.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of plugins for that kind of thing.  We've used [Easy Fancybox](http://status301.net/wordpress-plugins/easy-fancybox/) in the past, and it's worked well.

Comment: but i want to implement on my own, so i am fetching the image url from post but don't have any idea on bringing to lightbox because i have to identify whether the user clicks an image or not

Comment: You don't want to use a plugin?  Or you want to build a lightbox from scratch?  If you don't want to use a plugin, look at [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) - you could just incorporate that directly.  If you want to build one from scratch, good luck.  It'll be a lot of work with a lot of edge cases (browser considerations etc). To detect a click on an image you could use jQuery; something like: `$('img').click(yourhandler)`.  But if that's new to you, building a whole lightbox will be tough.

Comment: Thank you i wanted to start from scratch.Now i started from scratch as you told am using `$('img').click(myhandler)` and displaying a lightbox is not a problem but i don't know on which image user clicks because if we identify that then only we can easily display it in lightbox through img **src**

Answer (score 0):

try [nextgen gallery](http://wordpress.org/plugins/nextgen-gallery/). It is most used gallery plugin

Answer (score 0):

Huge-it lightbox plugin worked for me :) it's free and works on all previously uploaded images.